# Scale up to huge files

Tags: file, tree, large-data

Trees are described in flat text files. Each row contains the full path of a node and a value assigned to the node.

Here are two sample files :

```
File1 : slash separated paths
A/B/C : 1
A/B : 1
A1/B1/C : 1

File2 : dot or slash separated paths
A.C : 1
A.B : 1
A.B.D : 3
A.B.C : 1
A2/B/C : 4

Expected result : 
A : 8
A/B : 7
A/B/C : 2
A/B/D : 3
A/C : 1
A1 : 1
A1/B1 : 1
A1/B1/C : 1
A2 : 4
A2/B : 4 
A2/B/C : 4
```

We want to merge the two trees and generate a full layout of the tree.
We would like to have a java test case which will load two files, merge the two trees and generate a full description of the tree.
What would you do to scale up to huge files describing huge trees ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that you are expected to try and code this yourself _before_ you post a question here.

Comment: It seems to me you only need 2 routines: one for parsing these files into a storable form (sth like a string list plus an integer for the value, for each node), and a simple sorting routine for your structure. When written with reasonable care, it ought to work for any number and size of files.